# Databases created but table not crated in SQLite

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I want to create a database for Android Application using android studio 3.5 and using SQLite. i have using follow code, but using that code just database create not tables crete inside that database.
help me anyone.

```
MainActivity.java
package com.example.youtube;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    DbHelper myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myDb = new DbHelper(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you should use room library for database.

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you actually have in the DbHelper class

Comment: Try adding this permission in your manifest: 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: my project link https://github.com/gitam2869/YouTube

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Open Android Studio create new Empty Activity(File > New > New Project > Empty Activity)

I will give you a sample activity of add, display and delete using sqlite as database

Create **DbHelper.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> YourList = new ArrayList<>();
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "User_Database.db";
    public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "User_info";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
    public static final String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_SURNAME = "surname";
    private HashMap hp;

    public DbHelper(Context context){
        super(context ,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(
                "create table User_info(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,first_name VARCHAR,surname VARCHAR)"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS User_info");
        onCreate(db);
    }
    //Insert Data to SQLite database
    public boolean insertData(String first_name, String surname) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("first_name", first_name);
        contentValues.put("surname", surname);
        db.insert("User_info", null, contentValues);


        return true;
    }

    //delete all data in SQLite database
    public Cursor deleteData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete FROM User_info");
        return null;
    }

    //counting the number of items in your database
    public int numberOfRows(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
        return numRows;
    }

    //Get all item in your database
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getAllDatabaseData() {
        //hp = new HashMap();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from User_info", null );
        res.moveToFirst();

        while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
            HashMap<String, String> array_list = new HashMap<>();
            array_list.put("id",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
            array_list.put("first_name",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME)));
            array_list.put("surname",res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SURNAME)));
            YourList.add(array_list);
            res.moveToNext();
        }

        return YourList;
    }
}
```

Put it in your **MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText etfirstname, etsurname;
    ListView dataLV;
    Button btnSubmit, btnDelete;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String >>DataList;
    Context context = this;
    SimpleAdapter Adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etfirstname = findViewById(R.id.et_firstname);
        etsurname = findViewById(R.id.et_surname);
        dataLV = findViewById(R.id.data_listview);
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.Submit);
        btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.Delete);

        DataList = new ArrayList<>();

        DataList = new DbHelper(context).getAllDatabaseData();
        updateListView();

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String first_name = etfirstname.getText().toString();
                String surname = etsurname.getText().toString();

                new DbHelper(MainActivity.this).insertData(first_name, surname); //calling the method [inserData] in DbHleper.java Class
                DataList = new DbHelper(context).getAllDatabaseData();
                updateListView();

            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                new DbHelper(MainActivity.this).deleteData(); //calling the method [deleteData] in DbHleper.java Class
                DataList = new DbHelper(context).getAllDatabaseData();
                updateListView();

            }
        });

    }

    void updateListView(){

        Adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, DataList,
                R.layout.listview_data, new String[]{"first_name", "surname"},
                new int[]{R.id.firstname, R.id.surname});
        dataLV.setAdapter(Adapter);

    }

}
```

Put it on **activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_firstname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_surname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Surname"
        android:padding="10dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Submit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Delete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Delete"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/data_listview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

then create **listview_data.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/firstname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/surname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i used this code but same problem arises. means database created but table not.

Comment: can you update your post above, try posting the new MainActivity, DbHelper, Manifest, and the Error in Logcat

Comment: that one I gave you above that basically it.  Show us your progress then express your problem here again. Mutual efforts are needed to make things work here.

Comment: Ok lets do this step by step, whats your plan on your NewAccount activity? I presume you want to add account via this activity. Ok, first design your activity_new_account layout.

Comment: code works properly, but same problem arises means i can see my database but database not showing any tables inside it. so plz solve my issue.

Comment: how do you view your table?

Comment: first run app on emulator. then go to Device File Explorer -> data -> data -> package_name -> database -> database_name.db. after that right click on database and save as anywhere. then go to terminal and type sqlite3 database_name.db . after that run command means .tables. but database not show any table.